# Permission Denied htaccess in folders where no htaccess file even exists

Tags: magento2, overrides, htaccess, permissions, .htaccess

This permissions issue comes up in the server log. It doesn't stop the site from loading but it does stop a lot of the site from functioning. Some things I did fix through permissions but things like this keep popping up and I'm not sure if it is an Apache thing with rewrites or if this is a permissions issue. There's not supposed to be a htaccess file in this folder correct?

> /pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/.htaccess
>   pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
>   and that ... is executable

also errors for:

```
Magento_Paypal/
Magento_Braintree/
Magento_Ui/js/lib/ko/extender/
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/
```

I've gone all the way to 777 on files and folders in /en_US/ just to test and still same issue

What steps should I take to narrow this issue down? What permissions does `pub/static/` need in order to function? Also, if a mod_rewrite issue, how can I enable this for the root magento directory without doing in the `httpd.conf` file? When I look for mod_rewrite, I am not having any luck finding a way to ensure it is in fact enabled and working.

I have

- PHP 5.6.15
- Apache 2.4.16
- Easy::Apache v3.32.5 rev 9999
- MySQL 5.6.27
- Magento 2.0.0-rc.

`httpd.conf` directory setting:

AllowOverride All
Options All

Options All
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

AllowOverride All
Options All
Require all granted

Answer (score 4):

The web server user must have write access to the following files and directories:

- var
- app/etc
- pub

Magento also recommends setting the permissions as follows:

- All directories have 770 permissions. 770 permissions give full
  control (that is, read/write/execute) to the owner and to the group
  and no permissions to anyone else.
- All files have 660 permissions. 660 permissions mean the owner and
  the group can read and write but other users have no permissions.

source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html

In terms of the mod_rewrite issue in your `.htaccess` you should be able to change `RewriteBase /` depending on you configuration.

see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/.htaccess#L151