# Magento2: [HTAccess] Failed to open

Tags: magento2

When I try open link with image then I get 404 not found.

Log:

```
2020-05-17 11:33:29.128103 [ERROR] [10840] [HTAccess] Failed to open [/home/web/domains/catalog.website.com/public_html/pub/media/wysiwyg/.htaccess]: Permission denied
2020-05-17 11:33:49.211472 [ERROR] [10840] [HTAccess] Failed to open [/home/web/domains/catalog.website.com/public_html/pub/media/logo/.htaccess]: Permission denied
2020-05-17 11:33:49.266410 [ERROR] [10840] [HTAccess] Failed to open [/home/web/domains/catalog.website.com/public_html/pub/media/wysiwyg/.htaccess]: Permission denied
2020-05-17 11:34:00.722778 [ERROR] [10840] [HTAccess] Failed to open [/home/web/domains/catalog.website.com/public_html/pub/media/wysiwyg/.htaccess]: Permission denied
2020-05-17 11:34:00.722948 [ERROR] [10840] [HTAccess] Failed to open [/home/web/domains/catalog.website.com/public_html/pub/media/logo/.htaccess]: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url, I hope its useful to you

The web server user must have write access to the following files and directories:

> var
>
> app/etc
>
> pub

Magento also recommends setting the permissions as follows:

All directories have 770 permissions. 770 permissions give full control (that is, read/write/execute) to the owner and to the group and no permissions to anyone else.
All files have 660 permissions. 660 permissions mean the owner and the group can read and write but other users have no permissions.

**In terms of the mod_rewrite issue in your .htaccess you should be able to change RewriteBase / depending on you configuration.**

[Permission Denied htaccess in folders where no htaccess file even exists](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89650/permission-denied-htaccess-in-folders-where-no-htaccess-file-even-exists)